# `streamline` not plotting this vector field

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure, streamline

I am trying to test streamline with a very simple 3D vector field. I fill in a mesh using 3 for loops (not the best, but this is reminescent of a different expression for "v" which I couldn't easily vectorise). Then I define the vector field v as r. Simple radial field. My full code is below. quiver3 is fine, but unfortunately streamline gives me the following error:

> Error using griddedInterpolant
> Interpolation requires at least two
> sample points in each dimension.

```
N = 5;
L = 2;
dl = 2*L/N;
for i = 1:N+1
    for j = 1:N+1
        for k = 1:N+1
     
        x = -L + (i-1)*dl;
        y = -L + (j-1)*dl;
        z = -L + (k-1)*dl;
        
        X(i,j,k) = x;
        Y(i,j,k) = y;
        Z(i,j,k) = z;
        
        r = [x,y,z];
        
        v = r-r0;
        
        Vx(i,j,k) = v(1);
        Vy(i,j,k) = v(2);
        Vz(i,j,k) = v(3);
        
        end
    end
end

quiver3(X,Y,Z,Vx,Vy,Vz);
[sx,sy,sz] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:1:5,0:1:5);
streamline(X,Y,Z,Vx,Vy,Vz,sx,sy,sz);
hold on;
streamslice(X,Y,Z,Vx,Vy,Vz,[],[],5);
pbaspect([1,1,1])
```

Comment: I suspect that the issue is in the line ,  `[sx,sy,sz] = meshgrid(1,0:1:5,0:1:5);`   where you use effectively only 2D and not 3D (the scalar `1`) . If you use streamline(X,Y,Z,Vx,Vy,Vz) instead you wont get a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns back to gridded `X, Y`  variables, if you use transposed version of `X` and `Y`, you will not get this **interpolation error** in the streamline function. To transpose a N-D array in MATLAB, use `permute` function, like:

```
X = permute(X, [2,1,3]);  % to rearrange X and Y dimension
```

or just define correct form of `X` and `Y` at the first place [in the loop]

Comment: permuting X,Y,Z does not seem to fix things. How would I "define them correctly in the first place?". Thanks

Comment: if you use the command: 
streamline(permute(X,[2 1 3]),permute(Y,[2 1 3]),Z,Vx,Vy,Vz,sx,sy,sz);
you will not encounter the interpolation error. 
OR
in the loop, use:
X(j,i,k) = x;
Y(j,i,k) = y;